# Find all files OR directories (without contents) that match a name

Tags: bash, find, directory-structure

I'm trying to write a `find` command that searches for all files or directories with the name `andreas` in them (forward slashes added for clarity).

```
~$ find . -iname '*andreas*'
./Documents/Resume - Andreas/
./Documents/Resume - Andreas/Resume-Andreas-Renberg.odf
./Documents/Resume - Andreas/Resume-Andreas-Renberg.pdf
./Documents/Resume - Andreas/Resume-Andreas-Renberg-v2.pdf
./Documents/Resume - Andreas/Resume-Andreas-Renberg-v3.pdf
./Documents/Resume - Andreas/Resume-Andreas-Renberg-final.pdf
./Pictures/Trip with Andreas to Isengard/
./Pictures/Profiles/andreas-renberg.jpg
./.cache/junk/nothing here/hide-from-andreas.tar.gz
```

I *almost* have exactly what I need, but there is a huge amount of redundancy in that list that is causing problems in my other scripts.

Find already told me about the directory `./Documents/Resume - Andreas/`, so I don't want `find` to list all the contents of the directory that match too. I want the output to look like this:

```
~$ find . -iname '*andreas*' [command]
./Documents/Resume - Andreas/
./Pictures/Trip with Andreas to Isengard/
./Pictures/Profiles/andreas-renberg.jpg
./.cache/junk/nothing here/hide-from-andreas.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *prune* matches of type *directory*:

```
find . -iname '*andreas*' -print -type d -prune
```

From `man find`:

```
-prune True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, though the name `-prune` confused me. May I edit the answer to include the manual entry for `-prune`? Or could you add a short explanation of what the command does?

Comment: You don't need the `-type d` (nor `-print` one you"ve removed `-type d`)